# String assignment to uint8_t in c

Tags: c, string, uint8t

I am trying to assign string to `uint8_t` buffer in IAR, but I get a warning message.

`rx_buffer.rx_struct.RESP.RESPOND` is `struct field` of `uint8_t` type.

My code is:

`strncpy(rx_buffer.rx_struct.RESP.RESPOND, (uint8_t *)'NS,', 3);`

And the associated warning message is the following:

```
Warning[Pe1422]: multicharacter character literal (potential portability problem) 
Warning[Pe167]: argument of type "uint8_t *" is incompatible with parameter of type "char *",
Warning[Pe167]: argument of type "uint8_t *" is incompatible with parameter of type "char const"
```

I have written a workaround :

```
rx_buffer.rx_struct.RESP.RESPOND[0] = 'N';
rx_buffer.rx_struct.RESP.RESPOND[1] = 'S';
rx_buffer.rx_struct.RESP.RESPOND[2] = ',';
```

But I'm not satisfied with it. What is the correct way to do that?

Comment: use double quotes to make a string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using single quotes but you need double quotes (`"NS,"`) , and take a look to [Stop using strncpy already!](https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2013/04/03/stop-using-strncpy-already/), in this case it should work as expected because you don't want the trailing `'\0'`, but don't use it.

Use `memcpy` or `memmove`, also (as a question of style) don't use magic numbers like `3`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#define MAX_SIZE 3

int main(void)
{
    uint8_t arr[MAX_SIZE];

    memmove(arr, "NS,", MAX_SIZE);
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_SIZE; i++) {
        printf("%c", arr[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Your code is incorrect in many ways:

```
strncpy(rx_buffer.rx_struct.RESP.RESPOND, (uint8_t *)'NS,',3);
```

- The destination array does not have type `char *`
- the source is not an array: `'NS,'` is a multicharacter character constant, a non portable historic oddity that nobody would use in any decent code... casting it to `(uint8_t *)` does not fix this issue. You should just use double quotes: `"NS,"`.
- `strncpy()` is not the proper tool for this job. In fact it is never the right tool for any job.  This function is not a safe replacement for `strcpy`, it semantics are widely misunderstood, it is very error prone.  You should avoid using this function. In this particular case, it would just copy the 3 bytes as expected, but why use `strncpy()` when `memcpy()` is a simpler solution?

You can achieve your goal with this:

```
memcpy(rx_buffer.rx_struct.RESP.RESPOND, "NS,", 3);
```

or alternately by assigning each byte separately as posted in the question.  Both approaches are likely to produce the same machine code.

Answer (score 0):

`strncpy` expects its first two arguments to be of type `char *` and `const char *`, respectively. Instead of casting to `unit8_t *`, you should be casting to `char *`, if at all.

Also, `'NS,'` is a character literal, a string literal would be `"NS,"`.